# Amazon CloudFront: Cannot play a private video. Using Cloudberry and I don´t have RTMP or HTML options at "web url type" under "web url" tab

Tags: video, amazon-s3, private, amazon-cloudfront

I´ve just downloaded the pro version of CloudBerry (I´m in the 15 day trial).
I´m testing the software, and try to get a private streaming of a flv file that I have inside my S3 account. I´m using CloudFront also.
I´ve got the streaming ok, but I cannot get it to be played when I try to set an expiry date.

I´ve followed a tutorial, that tells me that after uploading the file and after setting the rigth policies, I should go to "web url" (rigth click of the mouse over the file in question), and set the expiry date. BUT I HAVE TO SET THE WEB URL TYPE FIRST.

And there are only two options there to select: HTTP or HTTPs. Not RTMP or HTML there.
So what should I do? I´ve treied with both options and cannot get it played (I´m using JWPlayer).

**Here´s how it looks like: http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/5312/problemr.png**

Hope someone can help me out!!
Thanks!!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not configured the streaming distribution on that bucket and that's why you don't see those options. The best way to find out if it is properly configured is to get  Properties from the context menu and to scroll down to see if you have Streaming Distribution section there.

If not, I suggest that you should run New CloudFront Distribution Wizard from the CloudFront context menu